# Can't MatchRow cells that contain more than a single value of data

Tags: excel, excel-formula

So at my new job I was tasked with setting up a price calculator fwhich compares prices between shipping companies. I received large chunks of excel data from the different shipping companies.

In their charts you pick which postnumber you want to ship to and what weight class the package undergoes. So all I have to do is get a Match result for the weight and the postnumber, to find the row and column number, so I can Index search this in the chart and receive the price.

Matching the user input for postnumber is easy because the input value matches the value in the charts.
But matching the user input to weight class is a bit more tedious.

Let's say our user input would be something like 356kg. The weight classes are something like:

1-50, 51-85, 86-125, 126-185, 186-250, 251-350, 351-450, 451-525, 526-635, 636-800

I've understood that you can't store more than one value of data in a cell, but is there a way around this? Were I can enter my input and it matches the row containg that number. Because now I have it set up  data validation as a dropdown menu for the weight classes in a cell, which is a bit excessive having to find the correct weight class for each shipping company.

Anyone see a way around this or is this were excel meets its limitations?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you can look into [`MATCH()`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/match-function-e8dffd45-c762-47d6-bf89-533f4a37673a) still:

[image]

Formula in `B1`:

```
=MATCH(356,A1:A10)
```

With the 3rd parameter ommitted, the default will be to *"finds the largest value that is less than or equal to lookup_value"*(MS).

If you don't want to match anything above 800 you can nest the above inside `IF()`.

Comment: Nice trick but the lookup array must be placed in ascending order for this to work.